# Entry UrI Format and ternary operators

Tags: craft3, entry-slug

I tried setting up a URL format that takes the hierarchy of a structure into account, but deals with the magic `__home__` slug transparently.

So I did this:

`{parent.uri == '__home__' ? '' : parent.uri}/{slug}`

Which works, but I wanted to tighten it up using the twig ternary `?:`, like this:

`{parent.uri != '__home__' ?: ''}/{slug}`

But that doesn't work at all, seems to choke on the `?:` part. Is that a bug, or just a short-coming of the URL format system (not being actual twig)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the ternary operator does what you want it to do. According to [this page](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators), the first part of your URL format would return `1` (true) if the parent uri is not `__home__`, or an empty string if it is.

You could try:

`{ parent.uri != '__home__' ? parent.uri }/{slug}`

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you,